# How to implement order-preserving encryption without CryptDB

Tags: encryption, cryptdb

Which cryptographic algorithm is suitable for implementing order-preserving encryption without using CryptDB?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using cryptdb"? I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Cryptdb is an implementation, not an algorithm. Are you really looking for an algorithm, or do you want an implementation? AFAIK cryptdb has an accompanying paper describing the algorithms it uses.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/how-does-order-preserving-encryption-work?rq=1