# How hypergeometric sampling works in order preserving encryption?

Tags: probability, order-preserving

According to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8800/53007:

> Start with the entire domain [M] and range [N]. Call y←N/2 our range
> gap. Now using our key k we generate some pseudorandom coins and give
> them to our HGD sampling routine along with y, M, and N. This gives us
> an x≤y that describes the number of points of our order-preserving
> function less than y.

What does the HGD sampling does exactly? It gives me a "good" or a "bad" ball at random? How can this give me any information about the number of points less than `y`?